# Filter only if another variable meets a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to conditionally filter a data frame. E.g. with diamonds dataset, if cut == 'Ideal', then filter price. Example sudo code:

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds |> 
  filter(if cut == 'Ideal' then price > 5000 else do nothing)
```

Is this possible with dplyr's filter()?

Comment: `filter(cut != "Ideal" | price > 5000)` should work. Basically you keep all rows where the price is over 5000 or the cut is not "ideal." If the cut is not "ideal", all prices will be returned

Comment: Thanks! Will use this to fall back on. But I wonder if there's a more explicit solution... just in case I pick up this script again in 6 months and stare blankly at this line trying to figure out why I did that!

Comment: You can make it more verbose: `filter((cut == "Ideal" & price > 5000) | (cut != "Ideal"))`

Comment: Yeah I like that one more

Comment: @DougFir, or just leave a comment for your future self :)

Comment: Yeah, reading it again I think I've made it click, it's quite elegant and probably obvious to most others already